# How can I sum up each columns of Time-Series Data per 5sec

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling, timedelta

I'm new to pandas and want to modify pivot table below.

```
beacon_name 6   12  16  23  24
detected_at                                                     
08:00:00    -86.500000  -150.000000 -150    -86.500000  -85.000000  
08:00:01    -78.500000  -150.000000 -150    -88.000000  -88.000000
08:00:02    -82.750000  -150.000000 -150    -81.500000  -87.333333
08:00:03    -83.333333  -150.000000 -150    -81.000000  -83.000000
08:00:04    -87.000000  -150.000000 -150    -86.400000  -84.000000
08:00:05    -88.333333  -150.000000 -150    -79.333333  -85.000000
08:00:06    -90.000000  -150.000000 -150    -85.750000  -86.750000
08:00:07    -150.000000 -150.000000 -150    -84.000000  -88.333333...
```

In detail, I want to sum up every 5 data-row into pivot table below.

```
beacon_name 6   12  16  23  24
detected_at                                                     
08:00:00     -418.05     -750     -750     -423.4     -427.3
08:00:05     -688.33     -750     -750     -417.22    -426.5
```

I searched and tried several approach, but was not able to obtain proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), but first convert times to `timedelta`s by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index)
df = df.resample('5S').sum()
print (df)
                 6     12   16     23     24
beacon_name                                 
08:00:00    -418.1 -750.0 -750 -423.4 -427.3
08:00:05    -328.3 -450.0 -450 -249.1 -260.1
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for quick response ! That works perfect